# automate testing in Flex

Tags: apache-flex

I want to automate testing of flex application. I have heard that Flex provides with classes that help you automate the testing. But I don't know where to find them and how to use them. Can anyone help me regarding this issue? Any hint or suggestion will be appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add to what Florian just said, that is one kind of testing which works with the Automation library.  Personally, that is not a kind of testing I normally do unless you create a lot of custom components and you need to test their behavior.

The testing you're probably referring to is Unit Testing.  In this case, there are several libraries available, but the one supported by Flash Builder is called Flex Unit 4.  In this kind of testing, we're testing functions to make sure the output is correct depending on the input.

You can find more [information about it on their website](http://docs.flexunit.org/index.php?title=Setting_up_a_FlexUnit_4_Project).  If you want automation, you're going to need an automation engine like TeamCity, or Hudson to run an Ant or Maven build.  If you're using Maven, I would recommend you look at [FlexMojos](http://code.google.com/p/flex-mojos/) for automated build and testing.

Comment: I checked the Unit4 and made the project as was illustrated there. I have a user interface but I don't know how to use that???

Comment: Wait, what?  What's the question? You don't know how to use the interface?  With FlexUnit, you don't really have an 'interface', you just have a page to tell you if the tests were successful or not.  If you have Flash Builder Premium, you don't need the interface since they come up in the IDE.  You need to add test cases/suites however on your own.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is called functional testing. Adobe provides automation for UI Components which allows third party programs such as RIATest, FlexMonkey, QTP, ... to record user interactions and replay them automatically.

[Testing and automation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS37cb61f8f3397d86-5906dd7a120892e4da7-8000.html)

Answer (score 1):

have a look at [Mockolate](http://mockolate.org/) and [Sikuli](http://sikuli.org/) to complement what's beyond FlexUnit

Comment: I actually want that I have a application in flex. I want that beside checking every functionality all the time whenever I do some changes in my application. I want something that once I write some test cases or script whatever...so that whenever I do change application..these test performs automatically and provides me with results...how can I go about it???

Comment: you need a continuous integration platform, that preferably works with your source control system. which one is up to you; there's Hudson, CruiseControl, and many others.

Comment: I use FlexUnit4 and it works great for me...In this I am able to write test cases and run them...Thanks everyone