# automate testing in Flex

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flex3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [automate testing in Flex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5428956/automate-testing-in-flex)

Hi,
I want to automate testing of flex application. I have heard that Flex provides with classes that help you automate the testing. But I don't know where to find them and how to use them. Can anyone help me regarding this issue? Any hint or suggestion will be appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [FlexUnit](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexunit/FlexUnit) testing framework. [Here](http://docs.flexunit.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) are nice docs.